# MySql date_add() query improvement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query that gets today's activity as at now() and compares it to activity at the same time for the past 5 days.

```
select count(*) ,date(timestamp) date , now() now  
from activitylog 
where timestamp>date_add(now(), INTERVAL -5 DAY) and 
      hour(timestamp) <=hour(now()) 
group by date(timestamp) 
order by date(timestamp) desc;
```

Is there a way of doing it more efficiently than the above way?

Comment: can you post the structure of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the query will return the day's activity up to the current hour for the current day and the previous 4 days, plus the current hour's activity only for five days ago - to make it include the whole day to the current hour for the fifth day, change the where clause to:

```
where timestamp>date(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)) and 
      hour(timestamp) <=hour(now())
```

Apart from this, the only issue I can think of is to check that there is an index on the timestamp column. Otherwise, it appears to be in its optimum form.

Comment: I was really hoping there's a way of using only 1 where i.e where timestamp(date_add(SOME_MAGIC_HERE)) and do away with the and hour(timestamp...

Comment: @artfullyContrived: Not if you want to exclude data from after the current hour in the previous 5 days.

Comment: Thanks. Lets keep it open for a day in case some other mysql guru comes up with something magical.